# Using an echo after a return in an if statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got some code, here, that's giving me some trouble.

```
    function rcMetaDisplayNone($content)
    {
        global $rc_options;
        global $post;
        global $login_button;

    $rcUserLevel = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rcUserLevel', true);

    if (!current_user_can('read') && ($rcUserLevel == 'Administrator' || $rcUserLevel == 'Editor' || $rcUserLevel == 'Author' || $rcUserLevel == 'Contributor' || $rcUserLevel == 'Subscriber'))
    {
        $userLevelMessage = strtolower($rcUserLevel);
        return do_shortcode( $rc_options[$userLevelMessage . '_message'] );
    }
    else
    {
        // return the content unfilitered
        return $content;
    }
}
```

The task I'm trying to conquer, here, is  how to append an `echo` to the end of the `if` statement, like so:

```
return do_shortcode( $rc_options[$userLevelMessage . '_message'] );
echo $login_link;
```

Now, by rules of how **PHP** works, I understand that this shouldn't work. My question is: how would I make it work? Is there a function or a workaround that will let me do this?

I'm a bit of a beginner to PHP, so I apologize if the solution is obvious.

**UPDATE**

Holy answers, Batman! Thanks for the help, folks. I should clarify. I've updated the code to include the *entire* function.

The `$login_link` code is essentially **outputting a link** that allows the user to log in (ironically enough). The `return` code, however, is **outputting a message** that, in context to this **WordPress plugin** I am using, is stating that the user does not have permission to access the content on the page.

See the dilemma here? I am trying to **append a log-in link to this message**. It's not simply an empty return value, but **an actual message outputting to the browser**.

**UPDATE 2**

This is a shortcode I'm using, so I'm not sure I can output said code outside of the function.

Comment: Addressing update: what I said below still stands you don't ever echo out in function.  In your case what you'll want to do is append your static string to the return so it'd be something like `return whatever()."MY STATIC LINK HERE";`

Comment: Awesome. Care to append that to your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot execute code after a `return` statement (in the function returning).

If I understand your problem correctly (executing `do_shortcode()` then showing the value of `$login_link`, then returning), then: Store the return value, call `echo`, and finally return the stored value.

```
$returnValue = do_shortcode( $rc_options[$userLevelMessage . '_message'] );
echo $login_link;
return $returnValue;
```

**Edit:** Based on your update, I believe you're looking for the following:

```
$returnValue = do_shortcode( $rc_options[$userLevelMessage . '_message'] );
return $returnValue . $login_link;
```

Comment: @JordanThornquest Done. Good luck! :)

Comment: It worked! Now, a quick question: how would I move the Login link to a new line? **Edit**: Ah, wait, @UnholyRanger's got it. Nevermind.

Comment: @JordanThornquest You wouldn't be able to unless you expanded the expression. For example, `$returnValue = ...; $returnValue .= $login_link; return $returnValue;`

Answer (score 2):

you would echo outside of the function.  Rule of thumb you should never echo INSIDE the function always return the output and echo the return set

So you'd do

```
<?php 
$echovar = rcMetaDisplayNone($content);

echo $echovar;

?>
```

**UPDATE USING YOUR FULL CODE**

```
<?php

function rcMetaDisplayNone($content)
    {
        global $rc_options;
        global $post;
        global $login_button;

    $rcUserLevel = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rcUserLevel', true);
    $staticstring = "<a href=\"blah.php\">THIS IS MY STATIC STRING IT CAN CONTAIN ANYTHING</a>";

    if (!current_user_can('read') && ($rcUserLevel == 'Administrator' || $rcUserLevel == 'Editor' || $rcUserLevel == 'Author' || $rcUserLevel == 'Contributor' || $rcUserLevel == 'Subscriber'))
    {
        $userLevelMessage = strtolower($rcUserLevel);
        $output = do_shortcode( $rc_options[$userLevelMessage . '_message'] );
    }
    else
    {
        // return the content unfilitered
        $output = $content;
    }
    return $output.$staticstring;
}

echo rcMetaDisplayNone($content);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Dave. Your answer was totally correct, as was Eric's. He was simply a little quicker to the draw in updating his answer. You guys both helped a lot!

Comment: no problems as long as you got your answer and perhaps learnt a little on the way :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not just PHP but the rules to how functions work. Once a `return` is hit, the function is done. This is so even if there is more lines after the `return`.

```
Function test(){
  echo "test";
  return;
  echo "done";
}
```

This will only output `"test"` since the return is hit. If you want to do anything, you need to make it happen before the end of a function, not when it's done.

```
echo $login_link;
return do_shortcode( $rc_options[$userLevelMessage . '_message'] );
```

So you can echo out the variable before returning.

**EDIT:**
Since what you are looking for is to add to the message after `do_shortcode`, you can concatenate the string before returning. Like so:

```
$shortcode = do_shortcode( $rc_options[$userLevelMessage . '_message'] );
return $shortcode."possible HTML".$login_link;
```

The "possible HTML" can be any string or formatting you may wish. Research `PHP String Concatenation`

Comment: Thanks, @UnholyRanger! Your edit helped with a subsequent question I had involving formatting my concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense, you could just move it to *above* the `return`:

```
echo $login_link;
return do_shortcode( $rc_options[$userLevelMessage . '_message'] );
```

It might be made more sense of if you gave us more of an idea of what you actually want to do (in a less abstract way than "output a value").

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Return will finish the function.
You can return what you need and then use echo where you call the function:

```
echo rcMetaDisplayNone($someParam);
```

You can return array of walues if you need more.

```
$returned = rcMetaDisplayNone($someParam);
echo $returned['echoVal'];
```